# Three divs in line which can scroll when overflowing

Tags: html, css, position

I want to build three divs in one line (each 33% width). One div has a child which content should scroll if its too big. Not the body!

I made a sketch:
[image]

I tried it with flex-boxes, but then the whole body will scroll. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you please post, what you have tried ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. As you resize the window the elements will also resize so you can scroll only when there isn't enough room to display all content.

```js
setWindowHeight();

function setWindowHeight() {
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  document.body.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
}

window.addEventListener("resize", setWindowHeight, false);
```

```css
.float {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
  background: #f00;
}
.center {
  background: #0f0;
}
.right {
  background: #00f;
}
.scrollable {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="float left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="float center">
    <div>
      Center
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable">
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
      <p>Scrollable</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="float right">
    Right
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Even though I can't get it working. Take a look at this live example: http://wernersbacher.de/pro/goldenminer/

Comment: It looks like it is very similar to what I made in the example. What are you having trouble with getting it working? If you dump that code into a single HTML file it renders fine.

Comment: I'm just not sure why it's not working: The body scrolls, not the inner div.

Comment: I solved it by using a flex box. You example has the same problem, the content above the scrolling div causes it to overflow the green box